# Memory Running Low - VM Swapfile vs Host Cache

Tags: vmware-esxi, ssd, swap

I have server running a VMware 5.5 hosting 3 VMs which are using all memory of my server.

I've just added a 120GB SSD but I don't know what tool to use it to smooth performance a bit.

Swapfile or host cache, which one should be correct?

Comment: You should have purchased RAM.

Comment: kkk! Unfortunately, all memory slots are being used and of course this SSD were vacated.

Comment: Adding disk resources to resolve a lack of memory doesn't quite seem like the right solution.

Comment: It's not a commercial environment, it's a gaming server. Why these functionalities would exists?

Comment: Even more so you should have bought RAM! If the game server swaps out then players will see higher latency and the server being occasionally unresponsive. It can completely ruin the gameplay.

Answer (score 1):

Both accomplish the same thing, adding a host cache automatically configures vSphere to use the SSD for the VM vswp files instead of the datastore hosting the VMs. So a host cache is definitely the way to go.

There might be an issue with getting ESXi to detect the SSD properly, [this link supposedly might help](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.storage.doc%2FGUID-C56B9994-24BF-4260-BABA-BAE38FFDCCED.html) (I can't verify how useful it is as VMware pages are down for maintenance at the moment)

But it will only improve performance by a bit, RAM is still a lot faster than flash. But since you have the kit, try it and see how it works, but be prepared to maybe replace some RAM sticks with larger ones at a later date.